# Trying to generate one sum for a set of multiple ids using SUMIF

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am a beginner in excel and I know this is a very basic question so I appreciate your help. I would like to scan down column A and for every instance that the id is the same, I would like to sum the number of years in column B associated with a given id, and have this sum displayed only in the first instance of the id in column C.

The code I am using now is below, but it generates sums in all of the cells. I would only like the first sum value for an ID to show in column C.
    =SUMIF(A10:A51254, A10, B10:B51254)

So an untouched set of data would look like this:

```
ID#    Number of Years  Total Number of Years
0151703   14.1  
0166079   7.0   
0166079   18.0  
0166079   1.4   
0173316   2.0   
0173316   4.0   
0173316   29.0  
0173445   3.4   
0173445   2.0   
0173445   4.0   
0173445   0.6   
0176104   22.7  
0176104   2.4   
0179961   2.4   
0179961   3.2   
0179961   9.8   
0179961   1.2   
0179961   3.3   
0183982   7.6   
0184823   17.6  
0184823   1.9   
0184823   1.6   
0185866   12.6  
0185866   3.3   
0185866   0.4   
0185866   1.6   
0187216   4.3   
0187216   12.9  
0187216   2.5   
0187216   2.0   
0188089   6.0   
0189745   20.0  
0192975   14.0  
0192975   6.4   
0194240   12.4
```

And the formula would generate this:

```
ID#    Number of Years  Total Number of Years
0151703   14.1            14.1
0166079   7.0             26.4
0166079   18.0  
0166079   1.4   
0173316   2.0             35.0
0173316   4.0   
0173316   29.0  
0173445   3.4             10.0
0173445   2.0   
0173445   4.0   
0173445   0.6   
0176104   22.7            25.1
0176104   2.4   
0179961   2.4             19.9
0179961   3.2   
0179961   9.8   
0179961   1.2   
0179961   3.3   
0183982   7.6             7.6
0184823   17.6            21.1
0184823   1.9   
0184823   1.6   
0185866   12.6            17.9
0185866   3.3   
0185866   0.4   
0185866   1.6   
0187216   4.3             21.7
0187216   12.9  
0187216   2.5   
0187216   2.0   
0188089   6.0             6.0
0189745   20.0            20.0
0192975   14.0            20.4
0192975   6.4   
0194240   12.4            12.4
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column `A:A` is sorted alphabetically. Let's suppose your header is in row 1 and first value row is 2. Write this in `C2`:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

Comment: Or, if unsorted, `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")`